# EF6 application won't store data in SDF database

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

It's been a while since I used EF and I'm now starting up a small project where I want to create a small database based on my model (classes in Domain folder), so simple EF Code-First.

I've been cracking my head on this, cause for some reason the tables do not get created in the database.

I've ran the project several times and the context does have plenty of seed logic to fill up several tables. The mapping is coded as well, as are the many-to-many relations and the unique constraints.

According to what I could find here the connection string seems correct as well.
It's the first time I'm using SQL Server Compact, as I want it to be an easily deployable WPF app. Maybe I'm overlooking something there?

I've added a screenshot of my environment which should contain all relevant information. If you need more, just ask.
[image: VS Screenshot]

Please help me finding what's wrong or missing, so I can finally start making some progress in this project. I've spend plenty of time trying to get past this hurdle.

Comment: The *name* of the connection string you pass to the `DbContext` constructor doesn't seem to match the one from the app.config. Inside the static constructor, check `db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString`

Comment: Thanks Ivan. I'd copied the variable name from the project setting, but when I add the full name, so including the settings path (<ApplicationName>.Properties.Settings), and solving some errors that came afterwards, it now stored the seeded data in the sdf file.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a copy of your database file in the bin/Debug folder, it will have your data!

Comment: That was one of the first locations I looked for. The issue lied, as Ivan commented on the OP, in the connection string name being incomplete.